# Reload listview when insert into database is complete or on back button Android

Tags: android, listview, onresume

Hi guys i'm really stuck on this and i'd appreciate help .I am inserting into a mysql database and when completed inside the button i am calling finish and it's going back to main activity but the list is not refreshing ?i tried to dothe OnResume and onRestart but the list is not showing at all ?

this is my  insert button  (main activity is called businessSide.java)

```
 //Add offer when button is clicked  and send  business id and business email to business side
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOffer);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String serverURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Codes/AddOffer.php";
                offerName = editNameText.getText().toString();
                offerLocation = editLocationText.getText().toString();
                offerDescription = editDescriptionText.getText().toString();
                offerType=type;
                Intent i = getIntent();
                businessId = i.getStringExtra("number");
                businessEmail = i.getStringExtra("email");


                new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successfully placed a new offer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Add_offer.this,BusinessSide.class);
                intent.putExtra("number", id);
                intent.putExtra("email", businessEmail);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            //    onBackPressed();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: its not posible beause by pressing of back button your list view doesn't reload. it shows u the same list as previous. but if u reopen your app then it shows the new items in list

Comment: I'd like to restart the previous activity then to show the uodated list  when finished the insert ?

Comment: can i see ur main activity code ?\

Comment: show your BusinessSide.class oncreate

Comment: b.putString("businessEmail", email); //Your id
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

Comment: remove youe comments i update your code approve that.

Comment: sorry say that again ?